# How do we formally construct a ball with greater radius from smaller balls?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

It seems to be a silly question but I just can't make the formalism right.

For example, in a metric space, we have all balls with radius less than or equal to 1, can we make all balls with radius r, r is real?

My approach is induction, we have a ball Bx(a) centered in a with radius x, x<1, we take the union of all balls B1(b) centered in b with radius 1, where b is in Bx(a). Intuitionally this is a ball with radius 1+x centered in a. But it cannot be proved by triangle inequality. Am I doing the right thing?

---

I assume all balls to be open

Comment: Use multiples of $0.5$ instead of multiples of $1$

Comment: Do you have open balls or closed balls?

Comment: Do the balls have to be disjoint?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have understood the question. I think you are asking
whether
$$B_{1+x}(a)=\bigcup_{b\in B_1(a)}B_{x}(b)\tag1$$
in a general metric space $M$, where
$$B_r(a)=\{u\in M:d(a,u)<r\}.$$

In general metric spaces $(1)$ is not true. Let $x=1/2$
and $M=\{a_1,a_2\}$ with $d(a_1,a_2)=5/4$. With $a=a_1$ the left side
of $(1)$ is $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and the right side is $\{a_1\}$.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I mean! So there is no way to construct greater balls from smaller balls?

Comment: @NEoYang Not in general, but you can put suitable conditions on your metric space to ensure it.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done (though perhaps something similar but a bit less ambitious might work).

To see that it can't be done, consider a set with two elements $X=\{a,b\}$. Define metrics $d_0$ and $d_1$ on $X$ by writing $d_0(a,b) = 2$ and $d_1(a,b) = 3$. For all $i \in \{0,1\}$ we have that the balls with radius $1$ or less in $(X,d_i)$ are just $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$. But $d_0 \neq d_1$.